# Query with two sums on the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

It's possible to create just one query which returns two sum's on the same column?

What I have:

**Sum of total sales**

```
select month(emitido_date) as mes, ifnull(sum((det.preco * det.quantidade) * (iva.valor/100) + (det.preco * det.quantidade) - (det.preco * det.quantidade * (det.desconto/100))),0) as total
from documento as doc
inner join documento_serie as serie on serie.id = doc.documento_serie_id
inner join documento_detail as det on doc.id = det.documento_id
inner join phos_iva as iva on iva.id = det.iva_id
where serie.documento_categoria_id = 3  and doc.rascunho = false and doc.exercicio_id = 4 
group by mes
order by mes
```

**Sum of settled sales**

```
select month(emitido_date) as mes, ifnull(sum((det.preco * det.quantidade) * (iva.valor/100) + (det.preco * det.quantidade) - (det.preco * det.quantidade * (det.desconto/100))),0) as total
from documento as doc
inner join documento_serie as serie on serie.id = doc.documento_serie_id
inner join documento_detail as det on doc.id = det.documento_id
inner join phos_iva as iva on iva.id = det.iva_id
where serie.documento_categoria_id = 3  and doc.rascunho = false and doc.exercicio_id = 4 and (serie.documento_tipo_id = 10 or serie.documento_tipo_id = 11 or serie.documento_tipo_id = 15)
group by mes
order by mes
```

***1st question. It's possible I have in the same query the return of one table with |Month| totalSales | SettledSales| ?***

***2nd question.On the second query, in the where clause, when the field `serie.documento_tipo_id` was 15, in the `inner join` of the table `documento_detail`, the field should be `doc.source_id` instead `doc.id`. How could I put this condition?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Case statement. Give this a try.

```
    select month(emitido_date) as mes, 
    case when (serie.documento_tipo_id = 10 or serie.documento_tipo_id = 11 or serie.documento_tipo_id = 15)
    then ifnull(sum((det.preco * det.quantidade) * (iva.valor/100) + (det.preco * det.quantidade) - (det.preco * det.quantidade * (det.desconto/100))),0)
    end settledSales,
    ifnull(sum((det.preco * det.quantidade) * (iva.valor/100) + (det.preco * det.quantidade) - (det.preco * det.quantidade * (det.desconto/100))),0) as totalSales
    from documento as doc
    inner join documento_serie as serie on serie.id = doc.documento_serie_id
    inner join documento_detail as det on doc.id = det.documento_id
    inner join phos_iva as iva on iva.id = det.iva_id
    where serie.documento_categoria_id = 3  and doc.rascunho = false and doc.exercicio_id = 4 
    group by mes
    order by mes
```

Since you mentioned that the inner join is different when serie.documento_tipo_id = 15..here's my suggestion. I'm not sure if this will give the result that you want and also I'm afraid that it's performance might be poor..anyway, I'll just paste it here. Hope it helps. :)

```
select mes, sum(settledSales), sum(totalSales)
from 
   (select month(emitido_date) as mes, 
    case when (serie.documento_tipo_id = 10 or serie.documento_tipo_id = 11)
    then ifnull(sum((det.preco * det.quantidade) * (iva.valor/100) + (det.preco * det.quantidade) - (det.preco * det.quantidade * (det.desconto/100))),0)
    end settledSales,
    ifnull(sum((det.preco * det.quantidade) * (iva.valor/100) + (det.preco * det.quantidade) - (det.preco * det.quantidade * (det.desconto/100))),0) as totalSales
    from documento as doc
    inner join documento_serie as serie on serie.id = doc.documento_serie_id
    inner join documento_detail as det on doc.id = det.documento_id
    inner join phos_iva as iva on iva.id = det.iva_id
    where serie.documento_categoria_id = 3  and doc.rascunho = false and doc.exercicio_id = 4 
    and serie.documento_tipo_id <> 15
    group by mes    
    UNION    
    select month(emitido_date) as mes,    
    ifnull(sum((det.preco * det.quantidade) * (iva.valor/100) + (det.preco * det.quantidade) - (det.preco * det.quantidade * (det.desconto/100))),0)
    settledSales,
    0 as totalSales
    from documento as doc
    inner join documento_serie as serie on serie.id = doc.documento_serie_id
    inner join documento_detail as det on DOC.SOURCE_ID = det.documento_id
    inner join phos_iva as iva on iva.id = det.iva_id
    where serie.documento_categoria_id = 3  and doc.rascunho = false and doc.exercicio_id = 4 
    and serie.documento_tipo_id = 15
    group by mes
    order by mes
    ) detail
group by mes
```

Cheers! :)

Comment: I will test your suggest and give already feedback ;) thanks in advance

Comment: Your suggest it's almost there :D It's just not working for serie.documento_tipo_id = 15, because when it happens, the inner join of 'documento_detail' has to be 'inner join documento_detail as det on DOC.SOURCE_ID = det.documento_id' instead 'inner join documento_detail as det on DOC.ID= det.documento_id'

Comment: Hi @HugoMachado! wasn't able to get back on you last night. I updated my answer. Hope it helps..but I'm afraid this might give a poor performance.

Comment: Your answer was almost perfect. I just had to change 'case when...sum(...)' to 'sum(case when ...'. Now, it's perfect. About the performance you mencioned, i don't know, but for me, it's perfect. I really appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome @HugoMachado. That's good to know. :) Glad I could help. Thanks :D